# Cannot log into Delicious using Yahoo! ID as username

Tags: account-management, yahoo, delicious

Since the revamp/relaunch of the Delicious site, I can no longer log in with my Yahoo! ID. Instead, I'm being asked for a Delicious ID. If I sign up, I will lose all my previous bookmarks.

I have thousands of bookmarks stored on Delicious.

Is there a workaround somehow so that I can log back into my account using my Yahoo! ID and not have it wipe or lose all my bookmarked stuff?

Comment: Can't use my username from Yahoo ID, and without username we're unable to use "forgot password". Believe I opted-in to transfer, but was given no new username in the process. You're stuck like me.

Answer (score 2):

> First step, if you haven't already, is to click the "forgot password?" link right below the password field on the Delicious sign-in form. A password reset link, along with a reminder of your username, will be sent to the email address associated with your account.
>
> If you don't get the password reset email, be sure to check your spam filter to make sure it didn't land there by accident. If, however, you can no longer access the email associated with your account or you used a dummy email account when you registered, you may just have to sign up for a new Delicious account.
>
> A couple of unique Yahoo! migration related log-in issues to note:
>
> 1. If you used to sign in to Delicious with your Yahoo! account, you will no longer be able to sign in to the new Delicious with that as your username. When you opted-in to the transfer to the new Delicious, you chose a new Delicious username to log-in with, and that's what you should be using moving forward.
> 2. If you never opted-in to the migration to the new Delicious, that means you never gave permission for your account to be moved and the account has been deactivated. Fear not though, we are working on a way to recover the bookmark data from the Yahoo! servers for those who missed the opt-in and still want to use Delicious. Once the recovery process is in place, you'll be able to save your old bookmarks and reimport those links back in to the new Delicious. I'll edit this post when this bridge is up and running.

[Taken from this Delicious support question.](http://support.delicious.com/delicious/topics/help_i_cant_login_what_do_i_do)

Comment: When you click 'forgot password' you then have to enter your userid - but if your userid was a Yahoo one then it won't work! This isn't a solution for Yahoo logins

Comment: @Kenny - have you read the full answer? In particular points 1 and 2 relating specifically to Yahoo accounts?

Answer (score 0):

As Kenny said, if you used a Yahoo ID to log in, you can't use it any more. I don't recall being prompted to choose a new Delicious ID, and even if I had been asked to, I would have chosen the same ID anyway, so I'm not too impressed that I can't access my bookmarks...